# What is correct method to execute curl from a subprocess?

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I was trying to invoke `curl` from `subprocess` to download images, but kept getting curl error (error code 2 ..which from doc refers to `CURL_FAILED_INIT`). I am not using `urllib` as i will eventually be executing a script using `subprocess`. Following is the code snippet

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def worker(fname, k):
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    i = 0
    for imgurl in f:
        try:
            op = subprocess.call(['curl', '-O', imgurl], shell=False)
        except:
            print 'problem downloading image - ', imgurl

def main():
    flist = []
    flist.append(sys.argv[1])
    flist.append(sys.argv[2])
    ...

    for k in range(1):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(flist[k],k))
        p.start()
```

### O/P:

> curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
>
> 2
>
> curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
>
> 2

....

Comment: Not to try to discourage you... but have you looked at Python's built-in [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) module? You can download images from within Python without having to shell out to any external program.

Comment: can you show us a usage example: command + ouput.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to run a shell command, subprocess is the way to go.  As this can start a shell command in its own process, use of multiprocessing is at best redundant.  Multiprocessing comes in handy when you want to run a function of your python program in distinct process.  You appear to intend to run a shell command, not a python function.

I am not familiar with `curl`.  If your intent is to get the standard output from `curl`, use `subprocess.Popen()`. `subprocess.call()` returns the program return code, not `stdout`.

See http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/subprocess.html

Something like:

```
subp = subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-O', imgurl], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

curlstdout, curlstderr = subp.communicate()

op = str(curlstdout)
```

might be closer. Not familiar with `curl` as I said, so your program may vary.